# Konvajs：Implement constraints similar to figm

Tags: konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

Konvajs：Implement constraints similar to figm
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQgqm.gif)

Konvajs：Implement constraints similar to figm

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you describe further what you require? Constraints can have many meanings.